# Problem with backing up USB stick using Disks utility

Tags: mount, backup, usb-drive, clonezilla, disk-utility

I am trying to back up the whole USB stick to external HDD by creating a disk image (*.img file) using the Ubuntu Disks utility.

The USB stick I'm **backing up** is the "**sde**" device. I entered: 
`lsblk /dev/sde` 
into the Terminal.

That outputted as:
[image]

Then I launched the **Disks utility**. When chosen "Create Disk Image" and entered the details (file name, where to save it) and clicked on the "**Start Creating**" button, I got this **message:**
[image: Disks error message]

**Why??** The **sde4 is clearly mounted** before launching the Disks utility. So why is the **Disks utility complaining that it's not mounted**??

BTW, here is how it looks now, after exiting Disks utility and typying `lsblk /dev/sde`:[image]

Comment: Backup with Disks using this cloning method should work, but it is very inefficient (will copy every byte as it is). If you still want this method, please unmount the partitions with `sudo umount /dev/sde` before starting the backup action using Disks. A more efficient alternative is to get a live drive with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) and make an image of the whole drive. It is smart enough to copy only the used blocks in the file systems (and skip the free space). You can also use the built-in tools `backup` and `restore` that you find in `usbdata`. These work on the file level.

Comment: See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data) for backup of `casper-rw`. You can backup `usbdata` with simple copying tools (also on the file level).

Comment: It seems to me that the **best option** to back up an USB stick is to use **Clonezilla**.
Quick question: Can I install it on **the same USB stick** that I want to back up?

Comment: You need a separate USB stick for Clonezilla. But it can be a small and cheap one, because the Clonezilla iso file `clonezilla-live-2.6.3-7-amd64.iso` is small: `File Size 289,406,976 bytes`, `md5sum b394e85c3a5df70a39569f4be966114a`, so a 512 MB stick is enough.

Comment: Question: Let's say that with Clonezilla I backed up a bootable USB stick with persistent storage and so I have now a *.img file. Will the restore process also create a bootable USB stick with persistent storage?

Comment: Yes, if you restore into a drive with at least the same size (not one single byte smaller) and, if GPT, you fix the backup partition table with `gpt-fix`. In order to know that the backup really works, please test restoring into an extra USB drive, whatever drive you have (pendrive, SD card, SSD, HDD). Use Clonezilla also for the restore task.

Comment: Try copy paste of the casper-rw partition in GParted. Casper-rw is the only difference between a Live and Persistent USB, thus the only thing that needs backing up in a Persistent USB. This only works if the OS is the same version on the USB's.